# drawing a right angled triangle pattern using python

Tags: python

here is my code to draw a right angled triangle

```
def printTriangle(width):
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,width):
       for j in range(j,i):
             print("*", end=" ")  # single line
             #j=j+1
       #i= i + 1
       print("* ")
```

the problem is that when the width is more than 3 it does not continue the pattern.This is the output am getting

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * 
* * *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatting in the question looks a little bit odd, but why do you restart `j` in `for j in range(j, i)`? That is, shouldn't you just go from 0 -> i?

```
def printTriangle(width):
    for i in range(0,width):
        for j in range(0,i):
            print("*", end=" ")  # single line
        print("* ")
```

Prints for `printTriangle(5)`

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Comment: i does appreciate your comment

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to have a loop inside a loop, in python you can multiply strings

```
def printTriangle(width):
    for i in range(0,width):
       print("* " * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `range()` is a good idea, so you can delete all of your initialisations. I'm guessing you would just need one for loop, because only the space inside the triangle varies for each line:

```
def printTriangle(width):
   # Top section is always a point
   print('*')

   # Middle section has two stars and varying space in between
   for i in range(width - 2):
      print('*' + ' ' * i + '*')

   # Base section is always a row of `width` stars
   print('*' * width)
```

You would want to avoid `width` ever being less than 2, but otherwise this would give you a triangle.